# How do I need to change the datatype in a textfile in order to read a String and not a Integer (C++/CLI, OleDb)?

Tags: c++-cli, oledb, oledbdatareader

My goal is it to read from a text file. This text file contains different columns and rows for each value. I can read the file as long as I don't change the datatype that windows set on its own. But I do not want the "plz" and "nr" column to be numbers (integers) but a text (String) value because a plz could contain values like "01979" and the nr could contain something like "4a". As a number the starting zero would be lost and this way something like a postcard would never reach its intended destination.

This way I need to change the datatype in a "schema.ini" file. But it doesn't work. I think I make some mistakes and do not follow the tutorial the way I need to do:  ["Schema.ini File"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Everytime I tried to read a String I got an Exception because it still want to read an Int32-values that I would need to convert into a string.

I did name the file "kunde.txt"

```
knr|nachname|vorname|plz|ort|strasse|nr
1|Müller|Johan|12345|Muster|Musterstr|1
2|Kummer|Freude|23456|Feeling|Gefühlswelt|4a
```

Col 0 = knr, 1 = nachname, 2 = vorname, 3 = plz, 4 = ort, 5 = strasse, 6 = nr

```
con->ConnectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    "Data Source=D:/C++/Quellen;" +
    "Extended Properties=text";
// ....
meineKunden->CommandText =
    "SELECT knr, nachname, vorname, plz, ort, strasse, nr " +
    "FROM kunde.txt ";
// ....
String ^ str;
while(reader->Read()){
    str += Convert::ToString(reader->GetInt32(0));
    str += " ";
    str += reader->GetString(3);
    str += " ";
    str += reader->GetString(6);
    str += "\r\n";
}
this->txb_Insert->Text = str;
```

My schema.ini

```
[kunde.txt]
ColNameHeader=True  
Format=Delimited(|) 
3=plz Char Width 5
6=nr Char Width 10
```

I did try with "Col3" instead of "3". I did use "Text" rather tan "Char", and I did even attempted it without Width. But everytime I got the same failure message. Even if i use 4 or 7 ... since I am not sure how it will be counted in the ini / txt file.

Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Die angegebene Umwandlung ist ungültig.
bei System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.ValueString()
bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
```

The exception is calls already by str += reader->GetString(3)
If I am correct column 3 contains plz, this way.

Could someone please say what I do understand wrong with the schema.ini file?
Since I could read the file without mistakes as long as I doesn't try to specific change the datatype in some columns the problems need to be with the ini file. At least I think so.

EDIT: I did change my ini-file to:

```
[kunde.txt]
ColNameHeader=True  
Format=Delimited(|) 
Col1="knr" Integer
Col2="nachname" Text
Col3="vorname" Text
Col4="plz" Text
Col5="ort" Text
Col6="strasse" Text
Col7="nr" Text
```

Now it works for "plz" but the exception is called in the last row, when I call the "nr". WTF?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain that the way you read data from the file suits the way it's written in .

So if the file in not written by you and you have to use it,try to know if it has a specific structure (for ex: fixed length record delimited fields , fixed length record fixed length fields.. etc) and use a way that suits this structure to read it.

Also try to know how fields of records are written in details because the way you read is the same as you write .

Comment: I did write the file myself.... it is a file from our first try to write into a file using C++. 
Now we did want to Read the txt-File by using C++/CLI and SQL in order to read the file.

And i did use int for the "knr" and for everything else we did use a String. This way it should work... at least I think it should. But it doesn't. >_> And I do not see the reason.

Comment: i can help only in the c++ part that is only reading the data from the file in a variables but not the database part .. but tell me to know how to help you.as you have to write data in a specific pattern that maintain you ca read it with it.. what is the structure you have written the file in?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdownload.acadox.com%2Fresource%2F56663%2F138535.pptx%3FAWSAccessKeyId%3DAKIAJM4VSPRIVX3JQ6WQ%26Expires%3D1557148905%26Signature%3DKeo3KXT%252FPB5Zs0SJKJmOFV4XwmU%253D see this link from page 12 about methods of filed and record organization

Comment: and here there is an example code of writing and reading using a specific structure https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdownload.acadox.com%2Fresource%2F56663%2F138608.pptx%3FAWSAccessKeyId%3DAKIAJM4VSPRIVX3JQ6WQ%26Expires%3D1557149615%26Signature%3DM1gGicTWtmTjeSch5u1a15xsY38%253D

Comment: Hi, I can't  open the links. It says only "unknown" and "no preview". 

I did ask my lecturer about this problem. He doesn't see any mistake in my ini-File or in my method. It should work but it isn't. Since col7 in the ini-file (they start to count with 1) and position (6) in the String (start to count with 0) it should work like it does with PLZ.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem and the file isn't this complex. I mean there are 7 columns (knr, nachname, vorname, plz, ort, strasse, nr).
Each line is for one set of information, each column is divided by "|"

In the ini I say what is the delimiter and that I even have column names.... to change the data type I even replicate the same column names.

Comment: Links are Lec4 & Lec5 here : http://www.acadox.com/class/56663#resources .. but tell me . how do you write data in file ? do you use this operator "<<" or you use a char [] and put your attributes i it then write it by (file.write()) or you write your attributes?.. I am not certain but i understand that you problem is that you can not read records in a string because it contains an int variable .. you can overcome this problem by writing the int attribute casted in the file to (char*)& or even the whole  object and read it in a dynamic char array. I am sorry if i understand the problem wrongly